# Problems with clearing cache and permissions on cache dir in Symfony2 projects on Windows

Tags: windows, symfony, caching, permissions, ntfs

I'm using Windows 10 and run various Sf projects on various versions of Symfony from 2.3 to 3.2. I've had these problems in all of them since forever (also on Win 7). In some projects it's permanent, in others incidental - when clearing cache, things go bonkers - sometimes it can't rename a directory, sometimes it can't delete a file, sometimes it can't open one. Examples:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException] Warning: file_put_contents(H:\_Moje_dydy\Documents\Projekty\atm\src/var/cache/dev/classes.map): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

This one is very common (but only in some projects!):

```
[Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\IOException] Cannot rename "H:\_Moje_dydy\Documents\Projekty\friendly_score\src_rainfin\app\cache\de_" to "H:\_Moje_dydy\Documents\Projekty\friendly_score\src_rainfin\app\cache\dev".
```

In some cases, complete wiping of the cache dir with admin rights helps. In some, it doesn't, and in some other cases it's completely impossible (deleting the dir's contents). Many times, when I was unable to delete the directory and looked into NTFS permissions on some folders within the cache directory I saw complete chaos like this:

[image]

Note repeated records for same users, multiple "special" rights (they have very weird sets of permissions within them, that often contradict one another).

In some "heavier" cases it not only interfered with the cache:clear command but also broke the application altogether. In most of those cases it needed very deep interventions to enable me to simply delete the cache dir (some subdirectories had so crazy permissions that even as admin user I was unable to delete them and had to mingle with permissions first).

Here's what I'm using right now:

- Windows 10 (happened on Windows 7 too);
- XAMPP with PHP 7.1 and Apache 2.4 (happened on older versions with PHP 5.6 and 5.4 too);
- Netbeans 8.2 as IDE (happened with previous versions too);
- cygwin to run CLI commands;
- git.

**My primary question is: what mingles with those permissions in such a crazy way?** Apache+PHP while creating cache on runtime? Netbeans, even though it ignores cache and log dirs (theoretically - I haven't specifically put them to ignore list in NB)? Git, even those these dirs are ignored in each repo (rather improbable)? Me, while running CLI commands via cygwin (also rather improbable)?

I've been battling it for a long time to no avail...

Do you guys have any insights on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i had  similar  problems....
Until  i switched  from xampp  to laragon

I know  that sounds  odd ,but in my  case  it solved all the problems.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony provides a documentation about these permission problems :
http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html

You can do either use umask(002) before you whole application, or set ACL.
ACL and umask both set a default access right for all new files.

Comment: I do realize that the folders need sufficient permissions to be writable by the Apache user. And that's not a problem. The problem is that even if I set proper permissions on cache folder, they get overwritten and totally messed up by something. And I don't know what that something is. And doc doesn't say anything about it.

Comment: The `setfacl` will solve your problems. As it is said in the doc, if you do a `setfacl -dRm ww-data:rwx your/folder` will set `rwx` right for ww-data user. The `R` param means recursive. The `-d` param means default. So all the new files and folders created in your/folder will inherit of the default permissions (in the previous case, www-data will have rwx persmissions)